# QFile::ReadAll() returning an empty array

Tags: qt, file-io

What are some of the common causes of this? My first thought was that the file im reading was readonly but I've checked for that.

The code that calls it is:

```
QFile histogramFile(fileName);
quint64 fileSize = histogramFile.size();
QByteArray histogramByteArray = histogramFile.readAll();
```

Comment: You didn't open the file, did you :)

Comment: yeah, that was the issue. doh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting from the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readAll):

> This function has no way of reporting errors; returning an empty QByteArray can mean either that no data was currently available for reading, or that an error occurred.

You can query the last error using [`histogramFile.errorString()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#errorString):

> Returns a human-readable description of the last device error that occurred.

In your case you forgot to [`open`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#open) the file, e.g.:

```
QFile histogramFile(fileName);
if (histogramFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    QByteArray histogramByteArray = histogramFile.readAll();
}
```